# Error when recalling directory to Collection View

Tags: ios, directory, uicollectionview, photo

I am using this code to recall the directory that I have made for each genre. However I get errors saying at the images part at the `[arrayCollectionImages addObject:image];` Can you explain what is wrong with the last piece of code. I also have an warning at arrayCollectionImages saying local declaration of arrayColectionImages hide instance variable. It is also telling me that the     `[[cell collectionImageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayCollectionImages objectAtindex:indexPath.item]]];` No visible @interface for "NSArray" declares the selector "objectAtindex:;"  What did I have done wrong?

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CollectionCell.h"



@interface CollectionViewController (){
    NSArray *arrayCollectionImages;
}


@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *allImagesArray = [[NSArray alloc ]init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Genre1";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell collectionImageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayCollectionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayCollectionImages count];
}
@end
```

This is my code for saving to directory

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FrontCamera = NO;
    cameraSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    captureImage.hidden = YES;

     [pickerViewContainer addSubview:SaveTopicker];

    arraygenre = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Tops"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Pants"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Coats"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Shoes"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Hats"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Others"];
    pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 800, 320, 261);


}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self initializeCamera];
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //fetch Category Name from the array used to fill the Picker View
    NSString *categoryName= [arraygenre objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:categoryName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:fPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    UIImage *image = captureImage.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:fPath atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method name is objectAtIndex:. You have the "i" in the method name in lower case which is incorrect.

Comment: So how should I change it?? I also changed the i into capital but it did not work? And for not misunderstaning which i of index are you talking about?

Comment: The "i" in the name "objectAtIndex". What error are you getting now?

Comment: The one that you pointed out is cleared however                     `[arrayCollectionImages addObject:images];` still has an error saying undeclared identifier "images" and warning of  local declaration of arrayColectionImages hide instance variable.

Comment: There is no variable called "images" in your code, hence the error. I am not sure why you are getting the main queue using dispatch_get_main_queue(). You do not need that since you are not doing anything in there which needs main queue. My suggestion is: if(data){UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; [arrayCollectionImages addObject:image];}.

Comment: Your warning for arrayColectionImages is because you have declared it as an instance variable and then also declared an array with the same name in dispatch_async block. You will have to remove the local declaration of arrayColectionImages from the block and use the instance variable instead.

Comment: I have changed my code again however getting another error No visible @interface for "NSArray" declares the selector "addObject:;".  Can you check my revised code and see if I have a miss that is causing the error?

Comment: It needs to be a NSMutableArray instead of NSArray. Also, I see that you changed the name of your local array to be "allImagesArray", but you are loading your collection view from "arrayCollectionImages". That won't work unless your "arrayCollectionImages" has some images. You can remove allImagesArray and just use arrayCollectionImages.

Comment: I am starting to think that the arrayCollectionImages is wrong.  I have reedited my question code, the place where the photo is saved.